# Serial code function in InstallForge

Tags: windows, installation

Does any one have any info on how to use the serial code checker functionality in InstallForge (http://installforge.net)?

You can generate a list of serial codes (and save them out to a text file) and the installer will then request a valid serial code from the user when installing, but I can't figure out if/where the serial code entered is stored or how to access it to store in the registry or use as an argument to an external program (such as calling a registration routine when the installer finishes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've worked this out...

[This post](https://installforge.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=2&p=2#p2) on the InstallForge site has a list of constants available within InstallForge.

It seems that they are not quite constant, and so `<Serial>` actually holds the value of the serial code that the user enters during installation.

In the Registry section of the InstallForge UI, you can create a new registry entry with the 'Value Data' value set to `<Serial>` (including the chevrons) and the user entered serial number/code gets written to the registry!

Just what I was looking for.

I dare say the other constants can be used in the same way... and it looks like they can also be used as arguments to any commands you choose to run at the end of the installation process.

Nice!